# How to access namespaced controller method under subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I namespaced my part of my application for admin and set it under a new domain like this:

```
namespace :admin, :path => "", :constraints => {:subdomain => "one"} do
    resources :cars
end
```

All my controllers and views are now in folder 'admin'.

Now I want to trigger EDIT and SHOW actions. How can I do it? Usually I would do it only like this:

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
    <%= link_to "Show", car %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_car_path(car) %>
<% end %>
```

What is the procedure when there is a subdomain and namespace? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are slightly wrong. You need to reference the subdomain in the `link_to`:

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
  <%= link_to "Show", admin_car_path(id, subdomain: "one") %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_car_path(id, car, subdomain: "one") %>
<% end %>
```

See [Railscast 221](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) for more info.

Comment: Thanks but for 'Show' action it gives me this error: `No route matches {:subdomain=>"one", :action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/cars"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: That is because you have not passed an `id` param to your `link_to`, it should look something like `link_to 'My link', admin_car_path(id, subdomain: "one")`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how it will be:

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
    <%= link_to "Show", admin_car_path %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_car_path(car) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that for 'Show' action I receive the following error: `No route matches {:subdomain=>"one", :action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/cars"} missing required keys: [:id]`